# kendo ui gird server paging send pageSize failed with asp.net web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I use below code to invoke web api to get the data, but how to send pagesize, skip to web api.

```js
   $scope.consulationWorklist = {
        dataSource:
            new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    data: "consultationItems",
                    total: "count"
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                transport: {
                    read: function (options) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "http://localhost:61274/api/v1/consultation/search/result",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                options.error(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 2,

            }),
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            //pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5,
            input: true
        },
        scrollable: true,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        resizable: true,
    };
```

ASP.NET WEB API CODE:

```js
[HttpGet]
[Route("search/result")]
public IHttpActionResult SimpleSearch(int pageSize, int skip)
{
    IEnumerable<ConsultationItemDto> result = _ConsultationService.GetAllConsultationItem();

    return Ok(new WorklistSearchResultDto
    {
        Count = result.Count(),
        ConsultationItems = result
    });
}
```

There are many discussion said that the kendo will send the pageSize and skip when setting the serverpaging to true. But not works. any one can help ?

Comment: The paging details will be in the `options` parameter of the `read` function on your datasource.  Pull them out and pass them to your json endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my approach I used the parameter map attribute to stringify the parameters so i can accept one DTO on WebAPI:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: svcSampleUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    parameterMap: function (options) {
        return kendo.stringify(options); //contains take, skip, sort, and filters
    }
},
```

and accepted this DTO at server end:

```
public class SearchDTO
{
    public int take { get; set; }
    public int skip { get; set; }
    public List<SortCriteria> sort { get; set; }
    public List<FilterCriteria> filter { get; set; }
}

public class SortCriteria
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}

public class FilterCriteria
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string operator { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

my WebAPI method then looked like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetItems")]
public SampleResponse GetItems(SearchDTO searchDTO)
{
    //Calling a different layer for the read operation based in the parameter values
    return BusinessLayer.GetItems(searchDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use url instead of read function,I resolved this issue.

```js
 $scope.consulationWorklist = {
        dataSource:
            new kendo.data.DataSource({

                schema: {
                    data: "consultationItems",
                    total: "count"
                },
                serverPaging: true,

                transport: {
                    read:
                        {
                            url: "http://localhost:61274/api/v1/consultation/search/result",
                            dataType: "json",
                        },
                },
                pageSize: 2,

            }),
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            buttonCount: 5,
            input: true
        },
        scrollable: true,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        reorderable: true,
    };
```